# Error when importing an Excel worksheet into Access table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am getting error `Run-time error 3125 'Import$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long` when I am attempting to import an Excel file to an Access Table. I **only** receive this error when other Excel files are open otherwise the Excel file is loaded to the table as expected. Here is some of the code I am working with:

```
Dim f As FileDialog, str As String
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
f.Show
On Error GoTo Err1
str = f.SelectedItems(1)

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True

Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Set xlWB = xl.Workbooks.Open(str)

'manipulate Excel file

'load spreadsheet
On Error GoTo Err2
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "JobCode", str, True, "Import!"
```

I originally thought and tried to change the filename, but was unsuccessful. It seems like the code is opening a new version of the import Excel file as Read-Only which might be confusing the Access database on which worksheet to import. But I am not sure why it's doing this and also why it only does this when another Excel file is open. Is this the problem? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Is `Import` the sheet name with the data you wish to import? If so, try setting the range `Import!A1:E100` for instance.

Comment: Import is the worksheet. I will test establishing a range.

Comment: I am still getting the an error using the more defined range Import!A1:E100 for example. Same issue - It works when no other Excel file is open.

Comment: (a) Are you sure that your workbook is Excel 97 or Excel 2000 format?  (b) What happens if you do a `xlWb.Close` before you do the TransferSpreadsheet command?  (I assume TransferSpreadsheet is accessing the file on the hard drive, so it might get upset if the file is in use within the macro.)  (c) Do you have a field name in your "Import" sheet which is "Import$" - it could be complaining that the field name is wrong  (d) Is the issue only occurring when you have other workbooks open in Access, or when you have them open in Excel?

Comment: What indicates Excel 97 or 00 format?

Comment: The second parameter (your "8") is a AcSpreadSheetType enumeration value.  "8" is the equivalent of acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8 and also acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9.  See [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196017.aspx) for full details.

Comment: Thanks. I will try saving and closing the worksheet and then importing.

Comment: I get the error on other open Excel workbooks. I've not tested other Access databases.

Comment: If you are opening the workbook in Access (using the Excel.Workbook object) while other workbooks are open in Excel, then it may be (probably is) using the existing instance of Excel to perform your manipulations.  If the file isn't closed, that instance of Excel could be locking the file and thus preventing Access from opening it to do the import.  If you didn't have an existing instance of Excel open, Access probably has to open its own instance of Excel, and therefore knows that **it** is the application that is "locking" the file.